# Redux toolkit & data fetch

Tags: typescript, async-await, fetch, redux-toolkit

Can someone explain to me why the parameter email is undefined when doing a data fetch from postgres db? How can I access the email or user in the exerciseSlice?

The user has been fetched and there is an email available to fetch data based on the email.  I'm sure it's something simple but I'm just not seeing it.

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const getExercises: any = createAsyncThunk(
  'exercises/getExercises',
  async (email) => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://localhost:5000/exercises/${email}`);
    if (response.ok) {
      const exercises = await response.json();
      console.log(exercises);
      return exercises;
    } else {
      const error: any = new Error(
        `Error ${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`
      );
      error.response = response;
      throw error;
    }
  }
);

const exerciseSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'exercises',
  initialState: {
    exercises: {},
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [getExercises.pending]: (state: any, action: any) => {
      console.log('fetching exercises...');
      state.status = 'fetching exercises...';
    },
    [getExercises.fulfilled]: (state: any, action: any) => {
      console.log('fetched exercises successfully');
      state.exercises = action.payload.exercises;
    },
    [getExercises.rejected]: (state: any, action: any) => {
      console.log('error fetching exercises');
      state.status = 'error fetching exercises';
    },
  },
});

export default exerciseSlice.reducer;



import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const accountDetails: any = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/getUserDetails',
  async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/profile/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { jwt_token: localStorage.token },
    });
    if (response.ok) {
      const user = await response.json();
      return { user };
    } else {
      const error: any = new Error(
        `Error ${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`
      );
      error.response = response;
      throw error;
    }
  }
);


const userSlice = createSlice({
  // State
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    user: {},
  },
  reducers: {
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [accountDetails.pending]: (state: any, action: any) => {
      console.log('fetching user...');
      state.status = 'fetching user...';
    },
    [accountDetails.fulfilled]: (state: any, action: any) => {
      console.log('fetched user successfully');
      state.user = action.payload.user;
    },
    [accountDetails.rejected]: (state: any, action: any) => {
      console.log('error fetching user');
      state.status = 'error fetching user';
    }
  },
});



export default userSlice.reducer;
```

[image]

Comment: How do you call the getExercises method? Are you sure you sent the email parameter?

Comment: The protocol error was due to using https instead of http.